# How to make a synchronous counter that repeats on a button press

Tags: button, counter, synchronous

Title says it all. I have a synchronous counter designed and working, and I can't figure out how to get it to count all the way down when I press a button. It's a 3 input counter with a 1 Hz clock and 3 JK flip flops.

Comment: What technology are you using? Are you talking about a programming language or electronics??

Answer (score 0):

Counting backwards would require a different logic design entirely.  A forward synchronous counter works simply by detecting falling edges of the previous bit, so each bit is dependent only on one input.  With an up/down counter, the next state of each bit depends on a logical combination of multiple inputs, [so a more complicated design is required.](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nd/surprise_96/journal/vol1/cwl3/article1.html#updown)